# Python: set average values to outliers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe

```
ID  Value
A   70
A   80
A   1000
A   100
A   200
A   130
A   60
A   300
A   800
A   200
A   150
A   250
```

I need to replace outliers to median value.
I use

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
grouped = df.groupby('ID')
statBefore = pd.DataFrame({'q1': grouped['Value'].quantile(.25), \
'median': grouped['Value'].median(), 'q3' : 
grouped['Value'].quantile(.75)})
def is_outlier(row):
    iq_range = statBefore.loc[row.ID]['q3'] - statBefore.loc[row.ID]['q1']
    median = statBefore.loc[row.ID]['median']
    q3 = statBefore.loc[row.ID]['q3']
    q1 = statBefore.loc[row.ID]['q1']
    if row.Value > (q3 + (3 * iq_range)) or row.Value < (q1 - (3 * iq_range)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
#apply the function to the original df:
df.loc[:, 'outlier'] = df.apply(is_outlier, axis = 1)
```

But it returns me median - `175` and q1 - `92`, but I get - `90`, and it returns me q3 - `262,5`, but I count and get - `275`. 
What wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and performant, with no Python for-loops to slow it down:

```
s = pd.Series([30, 31, 32, 45, 50, 999]) # example data

s.where(s.between(*s.quantile([0.25, 0.75])), s.median())
```

It gives you:

```
0    38.5
1    38.5
2    32.0
3    45.0
4    38.5
5    38.5
```

Unpacking that code, we have `s.quantile([0.25, 0.75])` to get this:

```
0.25    31.25
0.75    48.75
```

We then use the values (31.25 and 48.75) as arguments to `between()`, with the `*` operator to unpack them because `between()` expects two separate arguments, not an array of length 2.  That gives us:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
```

Now that we have the binary mask, we use `s.where()` to choose the original values at the `True` locations, and fall back to `s.median()` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how quantiles are defined

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([60,70,80,100,130,150,200,200,250,300,800,1000]))
print df.quantile(.25)
print df.quantile(.50)
print df.quantile(.75)
```

(The q1 for your data set is 95 btw)

The median is in between 150 and 200 (175)

The first quantile is 3 quarters between 80 and 100 (95)

The thrid quantile is 1 quarter in between 250 and 300 (262.5)